Is IELTS General accepted in US universities?
I took the IELTS General test a year ago and scored a band 8 in it. Back then my goal was to immigrate to an English speaking country. Things did not go as planned, and now I have decided to pursue a PhD in the US. I want to ask if universities will accept the IELTS General test. I have checked some universities' websites where I intend to apply to but they only mention IELTS - they do not specify whether Academic or General. I also emailed one university's PG admissions regarding this, and they just sent me some links to apply (nothing specific to my question).
So please let me know if I should just apply with my IELTS General score or take a fresh IELTS Academic and submit its score? The reason for asking this is because IELTS is very expensive to take in my country, so I want to make sure if I need to take it again or not. Thanks.
p.s. I'm not sure if this is the right forum to post this. I was stuck between posting on Academia or English language.

If IELTS is very expensive in your country and you're pursuing a PhD in the US, perhaps the TOEFL is an option. Neither is likely to be cheap, of course.

As far as I know, you need the academic IELTS for a university application.. Remember also an IELTS score has a two-year validity. IMO it is easier to achieve a 6.5 -7.5 in IELTS than its TOEFL equivalent.

Universities will say what is their minimum band requirement. It will always be at least 6.5,  an equivalent of level B2. For a phD course, I'd expect an average
score of 7.0 or 7.5 (Reading, Listening, Writing and Speaking paper). There is also the  DUOLINGO English test, which is cheaper but not as widely accepted or demanded by universities.

@Mari-LouA  Yeah I know about Duolingo test and TOEFL, but most universities don't accept Duolingo. TOEFL is I think as expensive as IELTS. So I think I better take the IELTS Academic test.

No,I don't think so any university (as can be seen here and here) would ever accept IELTS General. IELTS Academic and IELTS General are designed for two very different target audiences. Even the exam paper is set keeping in mind the people to be in two entirely different settings, for instance, in the Academic version of the test you are expected listen the lecture of a professor which is something not related to the General one. Similarly, in the writing part, you are asked to describe results and observations derived from a figure/chart/illustration, which is again not limited to when you are applying for an immigration(which is the actual purpose of IELTS General).
In some US universities, they even look at your reading and writing score that gauge your skills when you are in an academic environment. The questions in IELTS General assumes you are not in such setting.
In short, you cannot mix up these two tests,and the admission officer would simply not accept your IELTS General as a valid test.

Unless it's a typo, it seems Whitworth accepts IELTS General, making for a potential exception to the rule. Of course, Whitworth doesn't offer PhD degrees.

@Anyon Thanks for pointing that out. I think it's probably a typo because they don't even mention the academic test.
